# Rendering images in Django ModelForm instead of __str__ representation

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following django models / forms / views / html setup.
So I am rendering the InputFileForm in the html and the user should select from dropdown list a face_file that is saved in the Face model (preloaded via fixtures). I would like to have the face_file images to be rendered in the dropdown (alternatively a radio select would be fine as well) instead of the image str names - as it currently looks like the following:

[Image of current dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvx7T.png)

So in short: I would like to have an image rendered in the dropdown instead of the "Face 1", "Face 2",...

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
class Face(models.Model):
    face_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    face_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='../media/faces', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class InputFile(models.Model):
    input_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    input_flatlay_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='../media/flatlays', blank=True, null=True)
    input_face_file = models.ForeignKey(Face, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="inputs_using_this_face")
    input_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_inputs")



class Prediction(models.Model):
    prediction_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    prediction_inputs = models.ForeignKey(InputFile, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="prediction_inputs")
    output_lookbook_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='../media/lookbooks', blank=True, null=True)
    prediction_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_predictions")
```

I have a ModelForm for InputFile:

```
class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return mark_safe('<img src="%s">' %obj.face_file.url)


class InputFileForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta: 
        model = InputFile 
        fields = ['input_flatlay_file','input_face_file']
        widgets = {
                    'input_face_file': MyModelChoiceField(queryset=Face.objects.all()),
                }
```

In my views.py:

```
def prediction(request):
    form=forms.InputFileForm()
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.InputFileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None) 
        if form.is_valid():
            new_input = form.save(commit=False)
            new_input.input_user = request.user
            new_input.save()
            output_lookbook_file = util.prediction(new_input.input_flatlay_file, new_input.input_face_file.face_file)
            new_prediction = Prediction(output_lookbook_file = output_lookbook_file, prediction_user = request.user, prediction_inputs=new_input)
            new_prediction.save()
            return render(request, "modelgan/prediction.html", {"form": form, 
                                "new_input":new_input, "new_prediction": new_prediction })

        else:
            return render(request, "modelgan/prediction.html", {"form": form })

    return render(request, "modelgan/prediction.html", {"form": form })
```

In my html I am rendering the ModelForm as following:

```
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}

    <form action="{% url 'prediction' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <form action="" method="POST">
  
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_table  }}

            <input type="submit" value="Generate lookbook image">
        </form>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `label_from_instance` - see [ModelChoiceField.iterator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.iterator)

See also [Overriding the default fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields)

And than you can do something like following:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField

class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return mark_safe('<img width="60" src="%s">' % obj.face_file.url)


class InputFileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    input_face_file = MyModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Face.objects.all(), required=False, 
        widget=forms.RadioSelect)

    class Meta: 
        model = InputFile 
        fields = ['input_flatlay_file','input_face_file']
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to change "<img src="%s">" to "<img src=%s>" (to make it work in python, but not sure if will then render correctly in HTML though); However my biggest issue is that I get:

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'queryset'

Comment: @JoSp90, you can use single quote! I updated my answer.

Comment: @JoSp90, also add `queryset=Face.objects.all()` to `MyModelChoiceField`

Comment: Thanks @NKSM!
However, I then get the following "AttributeError: 'ModelChoiceField' object has no attribute 'to_field_name'"; it seems like the widget is not used here correclty?

Comment: @JoSp90, See [Field types > ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types)

Comment: @JoSp90, share full code that you now use.

Comment: I updated my code above (please let me know if there is a better way to share code again than updating initial question - I am new here...) thanks!

Comment: @JoSp90, Just tested on my server. I was wrong, I updated my answer)))

Comment: code runs now, however, the dropdown menu looks empty. do I need to adjust HTML file as well? (I am not able to add image here, but the dropdown menu is just white);

it seems to render correctly; I inspected the page, one example line is:

 <option value="1"><img src="/media/faces/face_1.png"></option>

And clicking on the link leads to a image

Comment: @JoSp90, Yes, right. Now you have to adjust your stylesheets

Comment: thanks!! do you have an hint / advice regarding stylesheets?

Comment: @JoSp90, you can use the following widget jQuery UI 1.11, [Selectmenu](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render)

Comment: Thanks!

do you know of a HTML way to do it (e.g. via radio buttons)? I basically just want to see the images and have the user select them. I do not mind whether it is a dropdown, a radio button select, etc.

Comment: @JoSp90, just add `forms.RadioSelect` to `MyModelChoiceField(... widget=forms.RadioSelect)`. See my updated answer.

Comment: @JoSp90, you can also add width to img in `label_from_instance` - return `mark_safe('<img width="60" src="%s">' % obj.face_file.url)`. Works fine for me just tested on my localhost.

Comment: Thanks @NKSM!!! This was the answer (both the RadioSelect and the width!) :-) Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your great support whit this

Comment: @JoSp90, happy to help !